# C++ single * and **

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand why these two lines produce the same result (test and test2).

```
customClass* test= (customClass*)*(uintptr_t*)(someAddr);
customClass* test2 = *(customClass**)(someAddr);
```

From what I gathered it's either double dereference or pointer to  pointer (in this case).

someAddr refers to pointer to pointer to customClass class in memory

Comment: C or C++? They are two different languages, especially for casting they have different rules

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry I did not know that, I have updated the tag, it is C++

Comment: what is `someAddr` ? what is `customClass` ?

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Either `someAddr` is convertible to `customClass*` or it's converatble to `customClass**` it can't be both; so we have Undefined Behaviour (when the pointers are dereferenced) regardless of the syntax tricks.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It refers to a pointer pointing to customClass in memory

Comment: @RichardCritten All object pointers are reinterpret-"convertible" to other object pointers. UB is a good guess though.

Comment: is it `customClass* someAddr;` ? Please add that to the question. It is always better to show the code instead of describing the code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Sorry I do not have the code of that, hence I am not able to describe. I have this address from a memory debugger, it looks like it's a pointe to pointer to customClass

Comment: you can write the code for that to have an example. Just adding that line would already make things a lot more clear (though initializing the pointer would be better)

Comment: @eerorika but `*(customClass**)` is a dereference and I think last sentence in 5) does not allow this (I might be wrong) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Comment: @RichardCritten hence: `UB is a good guess though`

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to understand why these two lines produce the same result (test and test2).

Because undefined behaviour means anything is allowed, even things that don't make sense<sup>1</sup>.

The value in `someAddr` is a pointer value, but that doesn't mean you can interpret it as whatever pointer type you like. What it points to is either a `someClass *`, or a `uintptr_t`, or something else, it can't be both at the same time.

Therefore *one* of those lines is breaking the strict aliasing rule, and thus has undefined behaviour. I would presume that it really is a `someClass **` value, so use an appropriate cast for that, i.e. `std::reinterpret_cast<someClass **>(someAddr)`

1. In this case, treating the value pointed to by `someAddr` as a pointer-sized number, then reinterpreting that as a `someClass *` matches how a `someClass **` is implemented. It would be ok to have

```
uintptr_t otherAddr; 
memcpy(&otherAddr, reinterpret_cast<void*>(someAddr), sizeof(uintptr_t)); 
customClass* test3 = reinterpret_cast<customClass*>(otherAddr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't read complex statements, break them up into lots of simple statements.

- `(uintptr_t*)(someAddr)` casts `someAddr` (which I *assume* is some form of pointer) to a pointer-to-`uintptr_t`.

  So, replace this with the statement

  ```
  uintptr_t* A = (uintptr_t*)(someAddr);
  ```

  - note that `uintptr_t` is defined as an [unsigned integer type large enough to hold a pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)
- `*(uintptr_t*)(someAddr)` is now just `*A` which is a reference to `uintptr_t`

  So, replace this with

  ```
  uintptr_t& B = *A;
  ```
- `(customClass*)*(uintptr_t*)(someAddr)` is now just `(customClass*)B`, which means we're converting the integer-large-enough-to-hold-a-pointer back into a pointer.

  See the second and third notes on [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast), and replace this code with

  ```
  customClass* test = reinterpret_cast<customClass*>(B);
  ```

So the first line ends up as

```
uintptr_t* A = (uintptr_t*)(someAddr);
uintptr_t& B = *A;
customClass* test = reinterpret_cast<customClass*>(B);
```

Notice that since `uintptr_t` is being used to hold a pointer, we're really treating the original address as a pointer-to-pointer. That's how we de-reference one pointer and still end up with a pointer.

Now look again at

```
customClass* test2 = *(customClass**)(someAddr);
```

and see it's doing *roughly* the same thing.

The problem is that although `uintptr_t` and `customClass*` are losslessly-convertible, that doesn't mean it's OK to either alias them or to assume they're layout-compatible. You still need to know what type of object you currently have, in order to correctly convert it to the other.

Which type you currently have depends on what was stored there originally, so only one of the statements can be correct.